# Losing File association for clickonce application after update (Win 8.1)

Tags: clickonce, file-association

I have a wpf clickonce application, which has a file association set.

Everything works fine on installation and update, except for windows 8.1

When the clickonce application is updated on Windows 8.1, the file association get broken every time. In fact the file association seems to be set to the old clickonce installation folder, which doesn't existe anymore. On other windows versions, this problem never occurs.

Here are a few other things I have noticed after the clickonce update on Windows 8.1 :
- cannot find the program with the "search function"
- program not listed in the "Add/Remove programs" list

How come I am encountering these problems, on Windows 8.1 only ?

How could this problem be fixed automatically ?

Comment: Same problem here with a WinForms application and Windows 10. File association breaks every time the app is updated. Any solutions?